# How to refresh the module configuration after change the etc/config.xml?

Tags: magento2, module, xml, configuration

I've created a module with default configurations into the `etc/config.xml` file, but I changed the default configuration and I'm not able to see them reflected into my module installed.

How could I refresh the installation to see these changes reflected in the admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove your module from the `setup_module` table.

```
DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE module='Rafaelcg_Quicklink`;
```

Remove all the custom configurations already configured.

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE '%quicklink%';
```

And check if the `etc/config.xml` is correct, for example, I have this file below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <quicklink>
            <general>
                <active>1</active>
                <timeout>2000</timeout>
                <dom_element>body</dom_element>
                <priority>0</priority>
                <ignores><![CDATA[/\/api\/?/]]></ignores>
            </general>
        </quicklink>
    </default>
</config>
```

Then run these commands below and check open the admin panel again.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```